# PHP Multidimensional Array to flat csv

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm working on a small analytics system that fetches information from different advertising sources and puts them into array. Now I need to export that information into flat csv for excel import or other reports software.

Here's the array

```
    Array (
        [site1] => Array
            (
                [source1] => Array
                    (
                        [campaign1] => Array
                            (
                                [ad1] => Array
                                    (
                                        [impressions] => 1141379
                                        [clicks] => 168
                                        [spent] => 113.0382
                                    )

                            )

                        [campaign2] => Array
                            (
                                [ad2] => Array
                                    (
                                        [impressions] => 612691
                                        [clicks] => 89
                                        [spent] => 78.0483
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )
    [site1] => Array
        (
            [source2] => Array
                (
                    [campaign1] => Array
                        (
                            [ad1] => Array
                                (
                                    [impressions] => 877042
                                    [clicks] => 87
                                    [spent] => 86.13
                                )

                        )

                    [campaign2] => Array
                        (
                            [ad2] => Array
                                (
                                    [impressions] => 238749
                                    [clicks] => 19
                                    [spent] => 18.81
                                )

                        )

                )

        )
    )
```

And this is the csv I ultimately want to have

```
    site, source, campaign, ad, impressions, clicks, spent
    site1, source1, campaign1, ad1, 1141379, 168, 113.0382
    site1, source1, campaign2, ad2, 612691, 89, 78.0483
    site1, source2, campaign1, ad1, 877042, 87, 86.13
    site1, source2, campaign1, ad2, 238749, 19, 18.81
```

I can do nested foreach cycle to process each exact value but is there a better solution like recursive function?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing out values or making recursive functions, consider using [fputcsv()](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.fputcsv.php).

This might just solve your problem immediately :D.

Here is an example from php manual:

```
<?php

$list = array (
    array('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'dddd'),
    array('123', '456', '789'),
    array('"aaa"', '"bbb"')
);

$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

foreach ($list as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}

fclose($fp);
?>
```

it will output:

```
aaa,bbb,ccc,dddd
123,456,789
"""aaa""","""bbb"""
```

Hope this helps ;)

**EDIT!** Recursively

```
function recursive($array) {
  $fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');
    foreach($array as $arr) {
      foreach($arr as $a) {
         if(is_array($a)) {
           return recursive($arr);
         } else {
           fputcsv($fp, $arr);
         }
      }
    }
  fclose($fp);
}
```

Comment: hmm, seems like I'll need to do
foreach site
 foreach source
 foreach campaign
 foreach ad
 fputcsv(advalues)

Correct?

Comment: yup, but still you will not loose or gain any memory usage from this. A loop is EXACTLY LIKE a recursive function. There is no loop that cannot be converted into a recursive function and viceversa.

Comment: well, thanks. I was looking for recursive function more for the sake of being more versatile - for example if I add extra array dimension like date, for example. In that case there will be no need to change the recursive function

Comment: here's the output

1141379,168,113.0382

1141379,168,113.0382

1141379,168,113.0382

(stackoverflow doesn't allow the line breaks but it's basically the values of first line without any key names)